# Have there been any measurements on the genomic differences between cancer cell DNA and healthy cell DNA?

Tags: genetics, cancer

I'm loooking for simple stats like the average number of base pair differences to normal cells, average diversity between different cancer cells, etc.

Comment: Check out dcc.icgc.org, a data portal dealing with what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two genome projects, which aim to identify the critical mutations (and by looking for them, they discover all the mutations in a given cancer) by sequencing DNA from the cancer cells and healthy cells from the same patient.

These are "[The Cancer Genome Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cancer_Genome_Atlas)" (TCGA) and "[The Cancer Genome Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer_Genome_Project) (TCGP)". Both project publish their complete data and ways to browse them. The data from the TCGP can be found in the "[Catalogue of somatic mutations in cancer](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic)" (COSMIC), the data from the [TCGA](http://cancergenome.nih.gov/) on their project site.